# Error message : "Error: Main method not found in class Conditionals, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)"

Tags: java

the code I already have is below. I am trying to input a double value and return a char value for grading purposes.
Using java code in jedit.
Keep getting error message "Error: Main method not found in class Conditionals, please define the main method as:
    public static void main(String[] args)"

```
public class Conditionals
{
public static double letterGrade(double score){
char result;
if (score >= 90.0)
{ result = 'A'; }
else if (score >= 80.0) 
{ result = 'B'; }
else if (score >= 70.0) 
{ result = 'C'; }
else if (score >= 60.0)
{ result = 'D'; }
else 
{ result = 'F'; }
return result;
}
}
```

this is the new code :

```
public class Conditionals
{public static void main(String []args){
System.out.println(letterGrade(60.0));
}
public static double letterGrade(double score){

char result;
if (score >= 90.0)
{ result = 'A'; }
else if (score >= 80.0) 
{ result = 'B'; }
else if (score >= 70.0) 
{ result = 'C'; }
else if (score >= 60.0)
{ result = 'D'; }
else 
{ result = 'F'; }
return result;


}
}
```

but when i enter 60.0 it returns 68.0

driver class:

```
public class ConditionalTest
public static main(String[] args)
```

as far as I got

Comment: Do what the error message tells you to do -- give your class a main method. And also, read a Java book, at least the first chapter, since you can't make this stuff up and expect it to work. Programming is an exercise in precision, and so you will have to learn the lingo and adhere to the rules, else the compiler will complain and the code will not function. So again, please follow your book, you won't regret doing this.

Comment: I switched it around and delcared  
    double score

now im getting the error message "error: cannot return a value from method whose result type is void
   return result;"

and I've been following my book and can't figure it out hints the asking for help on this forum

Comment: @Himz did you see my post? your code does not have main method

Comment: @Himz if you need any other help, lemme know

Comment: @kickbuttowski i included a main method and got it to compile but it returned wrong output

Comment: @Himz lemme see what is going on

Comment: Indentation is a thing that exists. If you use it, you won't be implicitly killing puppies.

Answer (score 8):

You need Main method inside your program so `JVM` can start execution or execute your code

The signature for the main method is

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

**public** is access modifier , so it is visiable to inside the class and other classes as well.

**static** means there is no need to create any object

**void** means this function returns nothing

**String[] args** means  command line parameters can be passed to Java program

so this is what it is missing inside your code.

Hope it helps

Another issue that you have is

```
public static **double** letterGrade(double score){
```

**the return type has to be char not double**

```
public static **char** letterGrade(double score){
```

Comment: that made it work perfectly, i appreciate the help

Comment: one more question, I have to implement a driver class could i get an example that relates to my code. Should the driver include the main method?

Comment: when you say driver class, it is the class that has main method

Comment: check my question again

Comment: you have already accept your answer so what is the issue?

Comment: @Himz did u solve ur issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
System.out.println(letterGrade(60.0));
```

to

```
System.out.println(Conditionals.letterGrade(60.0));
```

Comment: That does nothing.  He's making the call from Conditionals.main to Conditionals.letterGrade so explicitly qualifying it will have no effect.